# WhatsPopularWebPart as delegate control

Tags: sharepoint, delegates, controls, web-parts

I want to add the WhatsPopularWebPart as a delegate control. Registered a controlid in the masterpage and created a feature with this XML-manifest:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Control ControlAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.UI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" ControlClass="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Reporting.WhatsPopularWebPart" Id="WebAnalyticsDelegate" >
    <Property Name="Title">Most viewed pages</Property>
    <Property Name="DateRange">SevenDays</Property>
    <Property Name="ItemLimit">6</Property>
</Control>
```

However, the webpart keeps saying "Loading". I think the callback is not executed. When I look at the HTML, the WebPartId is only zeroes (0000-00000-00 etc.) instead of a valid GUID. Perhaps that is the problem? 
I want to add the webpart to every page on the site, therefore using delegate controls.

Answer (score 0):

Hum...

I don't see why it is not working. See this link :
http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/12/08/using-the-delegate-control-to-deploy-a-web-part-through-features/

Maybe it is a problem with This particular webpart : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/93782f9c-b582-436c-8c66-12349fd752b2

Have you tried with other webpart ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using delegates and the webpart is displayed too. However, it keeps saying "Loading", when I put the webpart directly on the page everything is fine... The webpart is display first, saying "Loading" and afterwards is updated with data (with AJAX or something like that). The update is not executed when used as delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: ContentPlaceHolder in masterpage and in every page layout a webpart zone in that ContentPlaceHolder. Further in the provisioning of the pagelayout an  with the webpart definition of the WhatsPopularWebPart. Problem solved.